# Compiling VirtualBox with error "makeself (variable makeself) not found!"

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I compiled VirtualBox with error *makeself (variable makeself) not found!* on SLES15.1.

The value of $MAKESELF was makeself, which was already initiated, and below lines were already added into global user profile.

```
alias makeself=`/opt/makeself-2.4.0/makeself.sh`
export MAKESELF=/opt/makeself-2.4.0/
```

I am confused on how to let check_avail() return true and pass the IF check in check_makeself(). Please advise and thanks in advance.

````
check_makeself()
{
  test_header "makeself"
  if check_avail "$MAKESELF" makeself; then
    makeself_ver=`$MAKESELF --version|grep version|sed 's+^Makeself.*version \([0-9\.]*\).*+\1+'`
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      log_failure "makeself not working"
      fail
    else
      log_success "found version $makeself_ver"
      cnf_append "VBOX_MAKESELF" "`which_wrapper $MAKESELF`"
    fi
  fi
}

test_header()
{
  echo "***** Checking $1 *****" >> $LOG
  $ECHO_N "Checking for $1: "
}

check_avail()
{
   if [ -z "$1" ]; then
     log_failure "$2 is empty"
     fail $3
     return 1
   elif which_wrapper $1 > /dev/null; then
     return 0
   else
     log_failure "$1 (variable $2) not found"
     fail $3
     return 1
   fi
} ```
````